# Grabbing enum value based on method parameter value

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, enums

I have an Enum that looks like this:

```
    enum PatentActions
    {
        AddMaterials=5,
        SelectLots=6,
        Verification=7,
        CreateTables=8,
        CreateExperimentals=9
    }
```

What I want to do is if I pass in "AddMaterials" in for the parameter "action" below...

```
public void clickAddMaterials (string patent, string action)
    {
        var chosenPatent = FindSpecificPatentRow(patent);
        int value = (int)PatentActions.AddMaterials;
        var btnToClick = chosenPatent.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:nth-child(" + value +")"));
        btnToClick.Click();

    }
```

I want it to grab the corresponding enum value of 5, and paste that in the variable "value", which will then be passed into the line below it.  The issue is I can't figure out how to make this line dynamic...

```
int value = (int)PatentActions.AddMaterials;
```

Right now it's hard coded to return the value for AddMaterials, but I want it to work for any of the enum values that may get passed into the method

Comment: [`Enum.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)?  Also, can you clarify in the question why you can't just use `public void clickAddMaterials(string patent, PatentActions action)`, and must use a `string` argument?

Comment: @SeanSkelly thanks.  If I pass in the enum itself, how/where will it know which one the user chooses?  The user is going to pass in one of the Enum values as "action".  I am not sure how that would work if I passed in the whole enum instead..maybe I am missing something

Comment: ...yeah, I think you're missing something.  A user of `clickAddMaterials(string patent, PatentActions action)` is only passing in one instance of the enum type, set to a specific enum value.  The 'whole enum' definition isn't passed in...

Comment: Ah, got it. Now it makes sense. Thanks!